# Conitional output in keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Maybe it is a dummy question but I'd like to know whether I can have my output vector to meet specific requirements.

I have multiple outputs (that are not binary) and I want their sum to be 1. I want my model to do some kind of evaluation in order for my output vector to meet this requirement.

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: if you want your outputs sum to be one why not use a softmax layer at the end? Because as far as I know doing arbitrary operations on output negates the whole learning part.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Can't I somehow feed the lstm with some kind of "prior knowledge" ?

Comment: what about the softmax activation for the output node?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Add a `softmax` activation at the end of your model, or
- Create a custom normalizing function

**Softmax:**

Just add `Activation('softmax')` at the end of the model.
This will perform some log operations though, and may be adding some extra conditions you do not want.

**Custom normalizing:**

Simply add this layer:

```
import keras.backend as K

Lambda(lambda x: x / K.sum(x), output_shape=optional_with_tensorflow)
```